# how the Next js and acf fields are looping objects

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql

In the next js I could see the other fields are coming except the ACF, how can I get the acf fields in the html.

```
 "flexibleContent": {
       

     "acfContentModules": [
                {
                    "fieldGroupName": "Post_Flexiblecontent_AcfContentModules_RawHtmlModuleGroup",
                    "rawHtmlModule": {
                        "fieldGroupName": "raw_html_module",
                        "rawCss": null,
                        "rawHtml": "Lorem Ipsum Raw html",
                        "rawJavascript": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

How Can I call the flexible contetn object in the [slug].tsx
I am getting the auhor title content but not the flexible content,

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
const res = await fetch('http://localhost/wp/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `
            query SinglePost($id: ID!, $idType: PostIdType!) {
                post(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
                    title
                    slug
                    content
                    featuredImage {
                        node {
                            sourceUrl
                            altText
                        }
                    }
                    date
                    author {
                          node {
                            name
                          }
                        }
                    flexibleContent {
                    acfContentModules {
                      ... on Post_Flexiblecontent_AcfContentModules_RawHtmlModuleGroup {
                        fieldGroupName
                        rawHtmlModule {
                          fieldGroupName
                          rawCss
                          rawHtml
                          rawJavascript
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        `,
        variables: {
            id: context.params.slug,
            idType: 'SLUG'
        }
    })
})

const json = await res.json()

return {
    props: {
        post: json.data.post,
    },
}
```

}

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import HeaderComponent from "../../components/common/Header/header";
import FooterComponent from "../../components/common/Footer/footer";
    export default function Post(data) {
    
         const post = data.post;
         console.log(post);
        return (
            <div>
                <HeaderComponent></HeaderComponent>
                <header className="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style={{'maxWidth':'1600px','minWidth':'500px'}} id="home">
              {/*<Image className="w3-image" src="" alt="" width={1600} height={800}/>*/}
              
            </header>
                <div className="w3-content" style={{'maxWidth':'1100px','marginBottom':'70px'}}>
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <Image width="640" height="426" alt="" src={post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl} />
                    <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}}></article>
                    
                </div>
                <div className="w3-display-container w3-content">
                    <p><b>Author: {post.author.node.name}</b></p>
                                <p><b>Date: {post.date}</b></p>
    
                     {/*<p><b>FlexibleContent: {post.flexibleContent.acfContentModules.Post_Flexiblecontent_AcfContentModules_RawHtmlModuleGroup.rawHtmlModule.rawHtml}</b></p>*/}
                </div>
                <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
            </div>
        )
    
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{post.flexibleContent.acfContentModules && post.flexibleContent.acfContentModules.length>0 && post.flexibleContent.acfContentModules.map(rawHtmlModuleItem => (
                    <div>
                        <a><h3> 
                        {  rawHtmlModuleItem.rawHtmlModule.rawHtml}

                        </h3> </a>
                    </div>
                ))}
```